# How to check that two files are equal in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and I need to compare two files. 
I did not find a function that does this, so I coded it myself. Below is the function I came up with.

```
cmpFiles :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO Bool
cmpFiles a b = withBinaryFile a ReadMode $ \ha ->
               withBinaryFile b ReadMode $ \hb ->
                 fix (\loop -> do
                   isEofA <- hIsEOF ha
                   isEofB <- hIsEOF hb

                   if | isEofA && isEofB -> return True             -- both files reached EOF
                      | isEofA || isEofB -> return False            -- only one reached EOF
                      | otherwise        -> do                      -- read content
                                              x <- hGet ha 4028     -- TODO: How to use a constant?
                                              y <- hGet hb 4028     -- TODO: How to use a constant?
                                              if x /= y
                                                then return False   -- different content
                                                else loop           -- same content, contunue...
                 )
```

My questions are:

1. Is this code idiomatic? It looks very imperative rather than functional.
2. Is this code efficient (Layz IO issues with big files, performance...)?
3. Is there a more compact way to write it?

Comment: It is not clear whether you use lazy or strict bytestrings (always show your imports!) [This](http://pastebin.com/E9U80KcD) is idiomatic lazy IO to me. I think your program will only work with strict bytestrings, `withBinaryFile` and lazy IO don't mix well.

Comment: Your function is too big. One simple step would be to write a separate function that takes two *handles*. `fix` is rarely necessary or helpful for writing clear code; explicit recursion is usually better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
cmpFiles a b = do
    aContents <- readFile a
    bContents <- readFile b
    return (aContents == bContents)
```

Comment: You might want to specify that this should be the `readFile` in `Data.ByteString.Lazy`....  Both will work, but the usual one might choke memory for large files.  The `String` version might be confused by the binary data.

Comment: What do you think of the color of this bikeshed? ```cmpFiles = liftA2 (==) `on` readFile```

Answer (score 0):

You can even make a one-liner out of it:

```
cmpFiles a b = liftM2 (==) (readFile a) (readFile b)
```

This one is actually equivalent to Reid Barton's solution. *Equivalent* is not a weasel word here, if you take the definition of `liftM2` from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#liftM2)

```
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) }
```

and insert `(==)` and the `readFile`s you are there immediately.

**Laziness** is your friend in haskell. [The documentation of readFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile) states that the input is read *lazily*, i.e. only on demand. `==` is lazy, too. Thus the entire `liftM22 ...` reads the files only until it finds a difference.

Comment: Laziness is your friend -- but the important part of this solution isn't laziness, it's the badly-named lazy IO. Lazy IO is your friend, too, [but only sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6669453/791604).

Comment: I digged into the code of (==) and it does seem to be comparing chunk of bytes, so I guess it is lazy indeed and therefore my worries of the operation to be loading the entire file before comparing were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmpFiles a b = (==) <$> readFile a <*> readFile b
```